# __asm__ statement and csrr instruction

Tags: assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, riscv, riscv32

I'm trying to write the following code :

```c
#define CONFIG_PMP_SLOTS 16
#define PMPCFG_STRIDE 4
#define CSR_PMPCFG_BASE  0x3a0

void csr_pmp_check(){
    for(int i = 0; i < (CONFIG_PMP_SLOTS / PMPCFG_STRIDE); i++)
    {
        int pmp_cfg;
        __asm__ volatile("csrrs %0, %1, x0"
                         : "=r" (pmp_cfg)      // output operand
                         : "r" (CSR_PMPCFG_BASE + PMPCFG_STRIDE * i )   // input operand
                         );
    }
}
```

But when i try to compile I get the following error :
test.c: Assembler messages:
test.c:9: Error: unknown CSR `a5'

I tried to replace :

```c
: "r" (CSR_PMPCFG_BASE + PMPCFG_STRIDE * i )   // input operand
```

By :

```c
: "i" (CSR_PMPCFG_BASE + PMPCFG_STRIDE * i )   // input operand
```

But if i do so i got an error telling me `warning: 'asm' operand 1 probably does not match constraints`.
Btw i compile like this :

```
    riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -nostdlib  test.c
```

Comment: Try `I` (capital). But that is just a warning anyway so it should still work.

Comment: I tried and I got this :
```
test.c: In function 'csr_pmp_check':
test.c:9:3: warning: 'asm' operand 1 probably does not match constraints
    9 |   __asm__ volatile("csrr %0, %1"
      |   ^~~~~~~
test.c:9:3: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
```
And no output is generated so i can't even objdump it to see what's going wrong

I aslo tried without -nostdlib just in case (i added a main toa void the warning on __start) but it doesn't work either

Comment: Ahha, you need a compile time constant there but since you used a variable this would only work if the loop was unrolled. As such it seems to work at `-O2`. You might want to mark the function with `__attribute__((optimize(2)))` (or figure out what specific optimization is needed) so it can be compiled even if optimization is not globally enabled.

Comment: I did this according to what you said :
```c
#define CONFIG_PMP_SLOTS 16
#define PMPCFG_STRIDE 4
#define CSR_PMPCFG_BASE  0x3a0

__attribute__((optimize(2))) void csr_pmp_check(){
 for(int i = 0; i < (CONFIG_PMP_SLOTS / PMPCFG_STRIDE); i++)
 {
  int pmp_cfg;
  __asm__ volatile("csrr %0, %1"
                   : "=r" (pmp_cfg)      // output operand
                   : "r" (CSR_PMPCFG_BASE + PMPCFG_STRIDE * i )   // input operand
                   );
 }
}
```
I compiled with :
```
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -nostdlib -O2 test.c
```
It doesn't seems to work either

Comment: And i don't get why unrolling the loop could solve the issue ?

Comment: Since each different `i` value needs to be embedded into the machine code (as an immediate operand), the only way for the `asm` statement to run with `n` different `i` values is to repeat it `n` times, i.e.e loop unrolling.  Otherwise `"I" (CSR_PMPCFG_BASE + PMPCFG_STRIDE * i)` won't actually be a compile-time constant.

Comment: You need to keep the `i` constraint.

Comment: I don't see any instructions that can take a CSR number in a register, unlike x86 `rdmsr`/`wrmsr`.  `csrrs` definitely needs the CSR number as an immediate; read the manual and look at the machine code format for it: https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf

Comment: Thanks for those answer, so : If i get it well it means that when i write CSR_PMPCFG_BASE + PMPCFG_STRIDE * i, the i value will not be reevaluate by the compiler since it's known at run time ? Then there is indeed no csrr instruction in the riscv spec. In fact when you re writing csrr it's an crrs instruction but with rs1 to 0 and the compiler is suppose to understand that. Just like when you're using li (load immediate) which doesn't exist in the spec but is understood by the compiler

Comment: Okay yeah with "i" and the __attribe__ statement i works, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

So this code seems to work. Thanks a lot to Peter and Jester.

```c
#define CONFIG_PMP_SLOTS 16
#define PMPCFG_STRIDE 4
#define CSR_PMPCFG_BASE  0x3a0

__attribute__((optimize(2))) void csr_pmp_check(){
    for(int i = 0; i < (CONFIG_PMP_SLOTS / PMPCFG_STRIDE); i++)
    {
        int pmp_cfg;
        __asm__ volatile("csrr %0, %1"
                         : "=r" (pmp_cfg)      // output operand
                         : "i" (CSR_PMPCFG_BASE + i )   // input operand
                         );
    }
}
```